# How can I selectively awk a string?

Tags: awk

If text lines of indeterminate width had in a file had text "Line-to-reorder", and I only wanted to flip and display the order of the first three tokens I can do:

```
# cat file.txt | awk '/Line-to-reorder/ { print $3 $2 $1 }'
```

How can I let lines of text that don't have the matching criteria pass through unaltered?

Secondly, How can I display the remainder of the tokens (the remainder of the line) on the matched line?

*(awk is the tool of choice since my embedded system's busybox implementation has it.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple script answers both your questions:

```
awk '/Line-to-reorder/ {tmp = $1; $1 = $3; $3 = tmp} {print}' file.txt
```

- you can assign to fields to edit the line
- no need for `cat`
- prints (all the fields of) every line

Comment: can golf it a bit: `awk '/Line-to-reorder/ {tmp = $1; $1 = $3; $3 = tmp} 1' file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to do any `if...else`, just do a match/not-match.

This prints fields 3, 2, and 1 followed by the rest of the fields in their original order if the line matches. If it doesn't, it prints the whole line as-is.

```
awk '/Line-to-reorder/ {printf "%s %s %s", $3, $2, $1; for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) {printf " %s", $i }; printf "\n"} !/Line-to-reorder/ {print}' file.txt
```

Broken out into an `awk` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
/Line-to-reorder/ {
        printf "%s %s %s", $3, $2, $1
        for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) {
                printf " %s", $i
        }
        printf "\n"
}
!/Line-to-reorder/ {print}
```

Run this with something like:

```
awkscript file.txt
```

This `awk` script takes a filename as an argument (because `awk` does) and so `cat` isn't necessary for either invocation method.

Answer (score 1):

best option is probably to match all lines (no pattern) and then do `if ... else` in the action.

something like

```
{
if ($0 ~ /Line-to-reorder/)
    print $3 $2 $1
else
    print $0
}
```

Comment: Even better. although I had to do:  if ($0 ~ /Line-to-reorder/) { print $3 $2 $1} else { print $0 } }

Answer (score 0):

This [reference](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-one/) may help