# How can I embed arguments in an awk script?

Tags: scripting, awk

*This is the evolution of these two questions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510175/how-can-i-collapse-this-bash-command-line-into-an-awk-statement), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479466/how-can-i-selectively-awk-a-string).*

For mine own learning, I'm trying to accomplish two (more) things with the code below:

1. ***Instead of invoking my script with*** `# myscript -F "," file_to_process`***, how can I fold in the '`-F ","`' part into the script itself?***
2. ***How can I initialize a variable, so that I only assign a value once (ignoring subsequent matches?***  You can see from the script that I parse seconds and micro seconds in each rule, I'd like to keep the first assignment of `sec` around so I could subtract it from subsequent matches in the printf() statement.

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/awk -f
   /DIAG:/  {
       lbl = $3;
       sec = $5;
       usec = $6;
       /Test-S/ {
           stgt = $7;
           s1  = $30;
           s2  = $31;
       }
       /Test-A/ {
           atgt = $7;
           a = $8;
       }
       /Test-H/ {
           htgt = $7;
           h = $8;
       }
       /Test-C/ {
           ctgt = $7;
           c = $8;
       }
   }
   /WARN:/ {
       sec = $4;
       usec = $5;
       m1 = $2;
       m2 = $3
   }
   {
    printf("%16s,%17d.%06d,%7.2f,%7.2f,%7.2f,%7.2f,%7.2f,%7.2f,%7.2f,%7.2f,%7.2f,%5d,%5d\n", lbl, sec, usec, stgt, s1, s2, atgt, a, htgt, h, ctgt, c, m1, m2)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a BEGIN clause:

```
BEGIN { FS = ","
    var1 = "text"
    var2 = 3
    etc.
}
```

This is run before the line-processing statements. `FS` is the field separator.

If you want to parse a value and keep it, it depends on whether you want only the first one or you want each previous one.

To keep the first one:

```
FNR==1 {
    keep=$1
}
```

To keep the previous one:

```
BEGIN {
    prevone = "initial value"
}

/regex/ {
    do stuff with $1
    do stuff with prevone
    prevone = $1
}
```

Comment: I wish I could hand out extra points for brevity and being on point.  Nicely done.